# Merge two pandas Dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Hi there i've got two pandas dataframes.

**data1**

| Player | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p1 | value1 | value2 | value6 |
| p2 | value1 | value6 | value7 |
| p3 | value1 | value8 | value9 |
| p4 | value6 | value6 | value6 |

**data2**

| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value1 | value8 | value6 |

I want to merge them so i get this table to work further

**Merge**

| Player | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| p2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| p3 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| p4 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can the dataframe `data2` contains more than one rows?

Answer (score 0):

No need for a join - just compare the values directly:

```
for i in data1.columns[1:]:
    data1[i] = (data1[i] == data2.iloc[0].loc[i]).astype('int')

print(data1)
  Player  1  2  3
0     p1  1  0  1
1     p2  1  0  0
2     p3  1  1  0
3     p4  0  0  1
```

Another way is to duplicate the rows in data2 and compare with data1:

```
data1[data1.columns[1:]] = (
    data1[data1.columns[1:]] == pd.concat([data2]*data1.shape[1]).reset_index(drop=True)
).astype('int')
```

Comment: Hi @mck,
i am getting a "raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: '0'"

Comment: with the second way i get this error:
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects

Comment: what are the index of data1 and data2?

Comment: in data1 row= Player, 1, 2, 3 .....; column= 0, 1, 2, 3... Like in your print(data1)
in data2 row= 1, 2, 3 column 0,1,2,3...

Comment: why does data2 have multiple rows? In your question there is only 1 row.